# Multiple tabs in browser from same website - session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, tabs

I am creating a website which has a list of buildings. Each building can be clicked on which then opens in a new tab with in-depth details and commands you can do on that specific building.

I had the problem of sessions where a session that was specific to the building was being shared across tabs. This I solved by appending a value to the session name so that it ends up being separate sessions.

My problem now is that each window waits for the other window to finish. So if I click something in one tab which takes 5 minutes to execute I cannot do anything with any other tabs until that one is finished.

Anyone can help me with why this happens and how I can fix it?
After doing a ton of research, I am literally stuck and don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Please show the code which opens the new tabs

Comment: I just say in javascript window.open

Comment: I'm guessing here... I assume here that you use webforms. It might has something to do with the fact that your connection to the server is reused. Having a session is not the same as a connection. Session is server side. Connection is between browser and host. Asynchronous communication is your answer in such a case. (update panels might do the trick)

Comment: The communication is asynchronus. I use callbacks to go back to the server.